# Updating volatile boolean array using Threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, concurrency

I'm a CS student currently learning about concurrent programming so my knowledge on threads is still, uh, tentative.

I'm just a bit stuck at the logic of updating a shared array with threads. I'm creating a program that allows a potentially infinite number of threads to constantly update a boolean array of size 10 to simulate the idea of a seating area where people can go in, sit down for a random amount of time, and then leave. Here is my code:

```
class Viewer extends Thread{
    private String name;
    private int index;
    volatile boolean[] seats;


    Viewer(boolean[] st, String n){
        seats = st;
        name = n;
    }

    public void run() {
        ViewingStand vs = new ViewingStand(seats);
        this.index = vs.findSeat(name, seats);
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            seats = vs.leaveSeat(name, seats, index);

    }
}

class ViewingStand{
    private volatile boolean[] area; //the array used by threads
    private int seatNo; //index of whatever area is being taken or left.
    Random rand = new Random();
    boolean found = false;

    public ViewingStand(boolean st[]){
    this.area = st;
    }

    public int findSeat(String s, boolean[] seats){
        this.area = seats;
        while(found == false) {
            for(int i=0; i < area.length; i++) {
                if(area[i] == true) {
                    found = true;
                    this.seatNo = i; 
                    area[seatNo] = false;
                    System.out.println(s + " has found a seat.");
                    return this.seatNo;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(s + " has started searching again.");
        }
        return -1; //should never reach this
    }

    public boolean[] leaveSeat(String s, boolean[] area, int n){
        this.area = area;
        this.area[n] = false;
        System.out.println(s + " has left their seat.");
        return this.area;
    }
```

The result of this program is the array initially getting filled with 10 elements (the size of the array I passed from the main program), those threads then leave 'an' array but clearly not the same one I'm passing back and forth between both ViewingStand methods, as every subsequent thread after the 10th gets stuck looking for a seat. Would love some input to point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: All access modifiers are shallow eg `final boolean[]` means you cant change the reference but you can change the contents of the array referenced. When you use `volatile` it applies to the reference but not the contents of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll ignore the concurrency issues at first and go straight for what seems like the logic error you're asking about - `leaveSeat` is setting `this.area[n] = false` - which seems to indicate that the seat is taken (your `findSeat` method assumes a seat is empty if the value is `true`).

On concurrency issues: You're likely to have issues with your loop checking the seats - it's possible for multiple threads to determine a seat is empty (and go into the if block), and all "claim" the same seat.  You should construct one instance of `ViewingStand` and have it manage access to the seats - using concurrency controls like `synchronized` or locking to ensure multiple threads don't modify the state of the seats at the same time.

Comment: I did everything you asked too, and will know it for the rest of my life, bless.

Answer (score 2):

On the concurrency side ...

1. A `volatile boolean[]` is unlikely to be thread-safe.  The `volatile` semantics apply to the array reference only, not to the access and updates to the elements of the array.
2. You performing a separate read and write on an element of the array.  Volatile means that a single read is guaranteed to see the instantaneously correct value; i.e. the value of the last write from any thread.  But it doesn't prevent race conditions.

   Your code, a thread performs a read to test if a seat is free followed by a write to reserve it.  That sequence is not atomic.  Nothing prevents another thread from "grabbing the seat" in between this thread's read and write.

Unfortunately, the only way to guarantee that your code doesn't have this kind of problem is to perform a *formal analysis* (i.e. construct a mathematically sound proof) starting from the specified semantics of the Java Memory Model<sup>1</sup>.  This is difficult.  Hence, the normal recommendation is to use the standard building blocks provided by the `java.util.concurrent`, `java.util.concurrent.atomic` and `java.util.concurrent.locks` packages.

---

<sup>1 - If you understand the JMM, an informal analysis may be acceptable ...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

On the code style first. The `Viewer`s are given raw access to the array. This goes against the philosophy of OO design. The boolean array should be encapsulated by the `ViewingStand`, handled only by the methods of it.

After the rewrite the code will look better, but still be wrong because of concurrency issues.

---

The access to the actual data, the content of the `boolean[]`, is not volatile. The way you use the keyword only make the reference to the data volatile. As the reference is not changed at all, the added `volatile` does not do anything except maybe make the access slower.

Even if you managed to have volatile reads and writes to the content of the array, there is still concurrency issues as the checking for a free seat and taking it is not atomic.

A way to make the access atomic is to add locks (make the methods `synchronized`), essentially forcing the access to the `ViewingStand` to happen one by one. With the "happens-before" ordering enforced by the lock, you do not even need `volatile`.

However if you add the lock to `findSeat`, the n+1<sup>th</sup> `Viewer` will hold the lock, keep looking for an empty seat, while the first n `Viewer`s wait for the lock so that they can run `leaveSeat`. A deadlock.
The `synchronized` keyword should be added to a method that loops through the array once but not the ever looping `findSeat` method.

---

Another way, and a powerful idea that you can apply even in database accesses, is [Compare-and-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap).
This is one instruction that changes the data only if the prior value is what you expected. Instead of `boolArray[i] = true`, you can use an array of `AtomicBoolean`s and do `atomicBoolArray[i].compareAndSet(false, true)`. If `compareAndSet` returns false, that means another `Viewer` has got the seat earlier.